# How to convert the dictionary below into a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

With the two code lines below, I got the two stocks' data in a dictionary as what illustrated below.

My question is how I can convert the dictionary to a dataframe with a column of `['Date','Ticker','Open','High','Low','Close','Adj Close']?`

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web

tickers = ['AAPL','MSFT']
start_date = "2019-12-31"
today ="2020-07-30"
    
two_stock_data = {ticker: web.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start = start_date, end = today) for ticker in tickers}
```

```
{'AAPL':                   Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  \
 Date                                                                     
 2019-12-31  289.929993  293.679993  289.519989  293.649994  292.163818   
 2020-01-02  296.239990  300.600006  295.190002  300.350006  298.829956   
 2020-01-03  297.149994  300.579987  296.500000  297.429993  295.924713   
 2020-01-06  293.790009  299.959991  292.750000  299.799988  298.282715   
 2020-01-07  299.839996  300.899994  297.480011  298.390015  296.879883   
 ...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...   
 2020-07-23  387.989990  388.309998  368.040009  371.380005  371.380005   
 2020-07-24  363.950012  371.880005  356.579987  370.459991  370.459991   
 2020-07-27  374.839996  379.619995  373.920013  379.239990  379.239990   
 2020-07-28  377.470001  378.200012  372.989990  373.010010  373.010010   
 2020-07-29  375.000000  380.920013  374.850006  380.160004  380.160004   

               Volume  
 Date                  
 2019-12-31  25201400  
 2020-01-02  33870100  
 2020-01-03  36580700  
 2020-01-06  29596800  
 2020-01-07  27218000  
 ...              ...  
 2020-07-23  49251100  
 2020-07-24  46359700  
 2020-07-27  30303500  
 2020-07-28  25906400  
 2020-07-29  22500400  

 [146 rows x 6 columns],
 'MSFT':                   Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  \
 Date                                                                     
 2019-12-31  156.770004  157.770004  156.449997  157.699997  156.833633   
 2020-01-02  158.779999  160.729996  158.330002  160.619995  159.737595   
 2020-01-03  158.320007  159.949997  158.059998  158.619995  157.748581   
 2020-01-06  157.080002  159.100006  156.509995  159.029999  158.156342   
 2020-01-07  159.320007  159.669998  157.320007  157.580002  156.714310   
 ...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...   
 2020-07-23  207.190002  210.919998  202.149994  202.539993  202.539993   
 2020-07-24  200.419998  202.860001  197.509995  201.300003  201.300003   
 2020-07-27  201.470001  203.970001  200.860001  203.850006  203.850006   
 2020-07-28  203.610001  204.699997  201.740005  202.020004  202.020004   
 2020-07-29  202.500000  204.649994  202.009995  204.059998  204.059998   

               Volume  
 Date                  
 2019-12-31  18369400  
 2020-01-02  22622100  
 2020-01-03  21116200  
 2020-01-06  20813700  
 2020-01-07  21634100  
 ...              ...  
 2020-07-23  67457000  
 2020-07-24  39827000  
 2020-07-27  30160900  
 2020-07-28  23251400  
 2020-07-29  19615300  

 [146 rows x 6 columns]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The value of each ticker key in the `dict`, is already a dataframe, accessible as `two_stock_data['MSFT']`
- Familiarize yourself with [`pandas-datareader`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader) functionality.
- As mentioned by [RichieV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6692898/richiev) in a comment, included here because comments get deleted:

  - `pd.concat(two_stock_data.values(), keys=two_stock_data.keys(), names=['Ticker'])`

    - This will create a multi-index dataframe, with `Ticker` & `Date` as the index levels.

#### Create a single dataframe

- The following code, adds a `ticker` column to each dataframe and then [`concats`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the dataframes into one.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web

tickers = ['AAPL','MSFT']

# create a dict of dataframes
two_stock_data = {ticker: web.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start="2019-12-31", end="2020-07-30") for ticker in tickers}

# add a ticker column to each dataframe
for k in two_stock_data.keys():
    two_stock_data[k]['ticker'] = k
    
# combine all the dataframes into a single dataframe
df = pd.concat(two_stock_data.values())

# display(df.head())
                  High         Low        Open       Close      Volume   Adj Close ticker
Date                                                                                     
2019-12-31  293.679993  289.519989  289.929993  293.649994  25201400.0  292.163818   AAPL
2020-01-02  300.600006  295.190002  296.239990  300.350006  33870100.0  298.829956   AAPL
2020-01-03  300.579987  296.500000  297.149994  297.429993  36580700.0  295.924713   AAPL
2020-01-06  299.959991  292.750000  293.790009  299.799988  29596800.0  298.282715   AAPL
2020-01-07  300.899994  297.480011  299.839996  298.390015  27218000.0  296.879883   AAPL

# display(df.tail())
                  High         Low        Open       Close      Volume   Adj Close ticker
Date                                                                                     
2020-07-23  210.919998  202.149994  207.190002  202.539993  67457000.0  202.539993   MSFT
2020-07-24  202.860001  197.509995  200.419998  201.300003  39827000.0  201.300003   MSFT
2020-07-27  203.970001  200.860001  201.470001  203.850006  30160900.0  203.850006   MSFT
2020-07-28  204.699997  201.740005  203.610001  202.020004  23251400.0  202.020004   MSFT
2020-07-29  204.649994  202.009995  202.500000  204.059998  19615300.0  204.059998   MSFT
```

#### Other Resources

- [10 minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html)